# Flutter- Conditional Statement-Buttons appear/disappear based on conditions set

Tags: flutter, dart

in the code below, the codes are correct, but there is problem in connected

when status!='connected!'- Connect Button appear- once connected - button disappears since status=='connected' as set in the code.

However, when status=='connected' actually, Disconnect button should appear. In  my case , it is not appearing.Please see the  code below, I commented out where I feel is the problem.

Like

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import './blecontroller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GetMaterialApp(
title: 'Flutter Demo',
theme: ThemeData(
primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,),
home: MyHomePage());}}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
TextStyle myStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30);  
final BleController c = Get.put(BleController());
MyHomePage();
@override Widget build(BuildContext context){   
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Thermometer test')),
body: Column(children: <Widget>[

  SizedBox(height:50),
            
  Obx(() => Text('${c.status}',
    style:myStyle)),
    
  SizedBox(height:50),
            
  Obx(() => Text('Temperature: ${c.temperature}',
    style:myStyle)),
    
  SizedBox(height:50),
    
  Obx(() => Container( 
    child: c.status != 'connected!'
      ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: c.connect,
          child: Text('connect',
            style:myStyle))
      : null)
      
      
      
      ),
      
      Obx(() => Container( //Button disconnect does not appear when status='connected'
    child: c.status=='connected!'
      ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: c.disconnect,
          child: Text('Disconnect Now',
            style:myStyle))
      : null)),


      
      
      ]));}}
```

blecontroller.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class BleController {
  final frb = FlutterReactiveBle();
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate> connection;
  late QualifiedCharacteristic rx;
  RxString status = 'not connected'.obs;
  RxString temperature = ' '.obs;

  void connect() async {
    status.value = 'Please turn on your device...';
    connection = frb.connectToDevice(id: 'F1:02:00:02:36:DB').listen((state) {
      if (state.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
        status.value = 'connected!';

        // get rx
        rx = QualifiedCharacteristic(
            serviceId: Uuid.parse("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
            characteristicId:
                Uuid.parse("0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
            deviceId: 'F1:02:00:XX:XX:XX');

        // subscribe to rx
// ignore: unnecessary_statements
        frb.subscribeToCharacteristic(rx).listen((data) {
          print("Hello");
          print(data);
          print(data.elementAt(5));
          print(data.elementAt(6));
          print((data.elementAt(4) * 256 + data.elementAt(5)) / 10);
          double final_temp =
              (data.elementAt(4) * 256 + data.elementAt(5)) / 10;
          String final_temp_value = final_temp.toString();
          temperature.value = final_temp_value;
        });
      } else {
        status.value = 'Connect Your Device!';
        
      }
    });
  }

  void disconnect() async {
    connection.cancel();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid null value in onpressed button. You will try this code

```
Obx(
        () => Container(
          child: c.status != 'connected!'
              ? ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: c.connect,
                  child: Text(
                    'connect',
                    style: myStyle,
                  ),
                )
              : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: c.disconnect,
                  child: Text(
                    'Disconnect Now',
                    style: myStyle,
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: replacing null with " " is showing this error" The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'"